# Django 3.2.7 + firebird database backend

Tags: django, firebird

Никак не могу подружить Django 3.2.7 и бэкенд БД Firebird на Windows (на Linux пока не проверялось)

Устанавливал и через pip и руками с git. результат один

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'firebird' isn't an
> available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above
> exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use
> 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
> 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

в settings.py указывал и 'ENGINE': 'firebird', и 'django.db.backends.firebird'. Результат один.

Установлены

```
Python 3.8.2
Django 3.2.7
fdb 2.0.2
django-firebird 1.11
```

Куда еще крутить ума не приложу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

тикет на гитхабе по данной проблеме висит открытый. проблема в импорте six

> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django_firebird-3.0a0-py3.8.egg/firebird/expressions.py",
> line 3, in 
> from django.utils import six ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'django.utils'
> (/home/arise/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/**init**.py)

на текущий момент самое простое решение - откатиться на джанго 2.2

```
pip install "Django~=2.2.0"
```

и ждать пока разрабы допилят бэк под джангу 3